# cant convert undefined to object

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object called `usersdata` whose output with `JSON.stringify(usersdata)` produces exactly this:

```
[{"ioid":"gDlMWAnLxEk8M3dKAAAF","user":"John","rank":"contributor"}]
```

all I want to do is get the values and wrap around html tags so I get an output like this:

```
<div id="gDlMWAnLxEk8M3dKAAAF">
 <span class="contributor">John</span>
</div>
```

so I did this:

```
 var udata = [];
 for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(usersdata)) {
  udata = value;
 }         
 userlist.textContent = "<div id=\""+udata[0]+"\"><span class=\""+udata[1]+"\">"+udata[2]+"</span></div>";
```

but I get an error that says `cant convert undefined to object`. Why is that?

Comment: your `usersdata` is an array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this way

```js
const
  userList  = document.getElementById('user-list') 
, usersdata = [ {ioid:'gDlMWAnLxEk8M3dKAAAF', user: 'John', rank: 'contributor' } ]
  ;
userList.innerHTML = '';
for (let {ioid, user, rank} of usersdata)
  userList.innerHTML += `<div id="${ioid}"><span class="${rank}r">${user}</span></div>\n`;

console.log('innerHTML ==>', userList.innerHTML );
console.log( JSON.stringify(usersdata) );
```

```html
<div id="user-list"></div>
```

Comment: On my actual code I get undefined. The funny thing is that I got a right output if I use userlist.textContent instead of userlist.innerHTML but then its plain text and not html. Why is that?

Comment: @snksaint  because you use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`

Comment: never mind, I had an undefined variable inside my code. Your code works perfectly, my mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In case you didn't notice, you declared `udata` as an `array`, but later on, you set `udata` to `value`, which *isn't* an array, and thus, you changed the type of the variable `udata`, which is why `udata[0]` doesn't work. 
I assume you want to add `value` to the array `udata`, but that's not how you do it! You have to do `udata.push(value)`.

```js
const usersdata = [{"ioid":"gDlMWAnLxEk8M3dKAAAF","user":"John","rank":"contributor"}]
var udata = [];
 for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(usersdata)) {
  udata.push(value);
  console.log(udata)
 }
```

would return

```json
[{
  "ioid": "gDlMWAnLxEk8M3dKAAAF",
  "user": "John",
  "rank": "contributor"
}]
```

so now, you just have to use

```html
userlist.textContent = "<div id=\""+udata[0].ioid+"\"><span class=\""+udata[0].rank+"\">"+udata[0].user+"</span></div>";
```

Here's an example with multiple user data:

```js
const usersdata = [{"ioid":"gDlMWAnLxEk8M3dKAAAF","user":"John","rank":"contributor"},{"ioid":"gDlMWAerefd3dKAAAF","user":"Jane","rank":"editor"}];
var udata = [];
let userInfo;
const userList = document.getElementById('user-list');
 for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(usersdata)) {
  udata.push(value);
  userList.innerHTML += "<div id=\""+udata[key].ioid+"\"><span          class=\""+udata[key].rank+"\">"+udata[key].user+"</span></div>";
  console.log("<div id=\""+udata[key].ioid+"\"><span          class=\""+udata[key].rank+"\">"+udata[key].user+"</span></div>");
 }
```

```css
.contributor {
   color: blue;
}
.editor {
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="user-list"></div>
```

Comment: `for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(usersdata[0])) {`

Comment: @Mister Jojo wWhat do you mean by that? it works...

Comment: okay but what about if I have more of one user like this? [{"ioid":"gDlMWAnLxEk8M3dKAAAF","user":"John","rank":"contributor"},{"ioid":"gDlMWAerefd3dKAAAF","user":"Jane","rank":"editor"}]

Comment: @Capt171 I mean `Object.entries(usersdata)[0][1] === usersdata[0] === udata`, and  your code is nonsens

Comment: @Mister Jojo I still don't seem to get what you're trying to say. My code works with `[{"ioid":"gDlMWAnLxEk8M3dKAAAF","user":"John","rank":"contributor"},{"ioid":"gDlMWAerefd3dKAAAF","user":"Jane","rank":"editor"}]` that @snksaint gave.            Also, your `for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(usersdata[0]))` gives `undefined` on my end with the Chrome console

Comment: `for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(usersdata[0])) console.log( key, value )`

Comment: the code shown is just there to show you what the `Object.entries()` method is for and that its use does not make sense for this answer